# Click on treeview nodes to open Webbrowser form

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I want to open form with WebBrowser control from Treeview nodes. Each node should open same form, but with different URL path for WebBrowser control. Here is what I tried:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

 'Define new page in Tab control and Webrowser form, which opens in It
  Dim New_Page As New TabPage()
  Dim WB As New Web_Form

  WB.TopLevel = False
  WB.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
  WB.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None

    'Select case for treenode clicks
     Select Case TreeView1.SelectedNode.Name
        Case Is = "Node1"
          'If Web_Form is opened, don't open new one, just focus to It instead
             If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Web_Form).Any Then
                For Each page As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
                   If page.Text = "Pictures" Then
                      TabControl1.SelectedTab = page
                   End If
              Next page
           'And If It's not opened, then open It in Tab control with setting focus on It
          Else
            New_Page.Controls.Add(WB)
            New_Page.Text = "Pictures"
            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(New_Page)
            WB.Show()

            WB.WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Pictures")
            TabControl1.SelectedTab = New_Page
          End If

       Case Is = "Node2"
           If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Web_Form).Any Then
             For Each page As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
               If page.Text = "Pictures" Then
                 TabControl1.SelectedTab = page
               End If
             Next page

           Else

              New_Page.Controls.Add(WB)
              New_Page.Text = "Documents"
              TabControl1.Visible = True
              TabControl1.TabPages.Add(New_Page)
              WB.Show()

              WB.WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Documents")
             TabControl1.SelectedTab = New_Page
            End If

        End Select

    End Sub
```

Currently my code opens form only once, whatever node I click, with correct URL for Webrowser. But then It doesn't want to open another one anymore. Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: I've managed to open form twice on different nodes,Now my problem is that when I close some form andy try to open It again from Node, It doesn't. Event gets fired again only If I click some other node first. How can I refresh/reset node after being clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. If anyone will ever need this - code to populate Tabcontrol pages with same form from clicking on Treeview nodes. A little bit long for just 2 nodes, but It can be shortened regarding your needs. Feel free for any better suggestions:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseClick

  'Define new page in Tab control and Webrowser form, which opens in It
  Dim New_Page As New TabPage()
  Dim WB As New Web_Form
  WB.TopLevel = False
  WB.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
  WB.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None

  'If user clicks node
   If e.Node.Name Is "Node1" Then
      Dim counter As Integer = 0
      'If Web_Form is opened, don't open new one, just focus to It instead
             If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Web_Form).Any Then
                For Each page As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
                   If page.Text = "Pictures" Then
                      TabControl1.SelectedTab = page
                      counter=1
                   End If
                Next page

                  Select Case counter
                        Case 1
                            'Do nothing
                            Exit Sub
                        Case Else
                            'Create new Tabpage
                            New_Page.Controls.Add(WB)
                            New_Page.Text = "Pictures"
                            TabControl1.Visible = True
                            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(New_Page)
                            WB.Show()
                            WB.WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Pictures")
                            TabControl1.SelectedTab = New_Page
                  End Select

              'And If It's not opened, then open It in Tab control with setting focus on It
              Else
                New_Page.Controls.Add(WB)
                New_Page.Text = "Pictures"
                TabControl1.TabPages.Add(New_Page)
                WB.Show()
                WB.WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Pictures")
                TabControl1.SelectedTab = New_Page
              End If
   End if

   If e.Node.Name Is "Node2" Then
      Dim counter As Integer = 0
           If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Web_Form).Any Then
             For Each page As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
               If page.Text = "Pictures" Then
                 TabControl1.SelectedTab = page
                 counter=1
               End If
             Next page

                Select Case counter
                        Case 1
                            'Do nothing
                            Exit Sub
                        Case Else
                            'Create new Tabpage
                            New_Page.Controls.Add(WB)
                            New_Page.Text = "Documents"
                            TabControl1.Visible = True
                            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(New_Page)
                            WB.Show()
                            WB.WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Documents")
                            TabControl1.SelectedTab = New_Page
                End Select
           Else
              New_Page.Controls.Add(WB)
              New_Page.Text = "Documents"
              TabControl1.Visible = True
              TabControl1.TabPages.Add(New_Page)
              WB.Show()
              WB.WebBrowser1.Navigate("C:\Documents")
             TabControl1.SelectedTab = New_Page
           End If

    End if 

End Sub
```